# Is there any way to implement all the formulas that are supported by Excel , into Java?

Tags: java, excel

I want my program to support all the formulas that one can use in Excel file into java code.

The requirement was that all the functions that are supported by excel both mathematical and logical like (add, multiply, substract or 'OR', 'IF') and others like Vlookup etc into java with the same format?

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Apache NPOI Project](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/formula.html) seems to support Excel formulas. Some examples are available [here](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html#common-formulas).